# Why ObservableList saves only one element ?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm triying to add "players" to `ObservableList` through a `TextField` text.

```
    @FXML   
 void ingresar_tabla(){
     String jugador = t_ingresarjudaror.getText();
     Jugador juga = new Jugador(jugador);
     lista_Jugadores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     lista_Jugadores.add(juga);
     juga.setNombre(jugador);
     colJugador.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nombre"));
     t_tabla.setItems(lista_Jugadores);
     t_tabla.refresh();
     System.out.println(lista_Jugadores);        


 }
```

My problem is that each time I enter a new name in the textfield, the list saves only the last value.

How can I keep all records?

Comment: Pretty sure this `lista_Jugadores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` is creating a new list every time. Remove it and only create the list once.

Comment: Yes is what i think, but if i remove it, throws error on console, i  will try to add it elsewhere

Comment: don't remove lista_Jugadores = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); just make your initialisation out the method.

Comment: as to your problem: the others are spot on. For further help, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly. Also note: whatever you do, dont use table.refresh ... never-ever!! If it feels like you need it, there's something wrong with the setup: a properly configured table will update itself on setItems (or any modification of the data list)

Answer (score 0):

```
lista_Jugadores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

creates an `ObservableList` each time your program call `ingresar_tabla()`

So just move this line `lista_Jugadores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

out your method like this :

```
 ObeservableList<Jugador> lista_Jugadores =   FXCollections.observableArrayList();
colJugador.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nombre"));
   @FXML   
  void ingresar_tabla(){
     String jugador = t_ingresarjudaror.getText();
     Jugador juga = new Jugador(jugador);
     lista_Jugadores.add(juga);
     juga.setNombre(jugador);
     t_tabla.setItems(lista_Jugadores);
     System.out.println(lista_Jugadores);        


 }
```

Comment: you don't _have_ to replicate all errors of the question ;) Dont refresh, dont reset the valueFactory, don't re-set the items - all that's required is the add of the new Player.

Comment: In originally ,he can remove the LisView but I answered considering what he wants.

Comment: better ... now remove the setItems and all is fine :)